# ThreadPoolExecutor executing in single thread even though corePoolSize is set more

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

My problem is related to the executor returned by `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` which is explained after the following program:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    List<Runnable> runnableList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        runnableList.add(task(atomicInteger.incrementAndGet(), threadPoolExecutor));
    }
    System.out.println("Starting Stage-1.");
    threadPoolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    runnableList.forEach(threadPoolExecutor::execute);

    waitForCompletion(threadPoolExecutor);
    System.out.println("Stage-1 complete.");

    threadPoolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(0);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);

    System.out.println("Starting Stage-2.");
    threadPoolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(6);
    runnableList.forEach(threadPoolExecutor::execute);

    waitForCompletion(threadPoolExecutor);
    System.out.println("Stage-2 complete.");
    threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
}

static Runnable task(int count, ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor) {
    return () -> {
        LocalTime start;
        LocalTime end;
        try {
            start = LocalTime.now();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            end = LocalTime.now();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String log = "Thread: " + count +
                ",  Start: " + start +
                ",  Stop: " + end +
                ",  ActiveCount: " + threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() +
                ",  CorePoolSize: " + threadPoolExecutor.getCorePoolSize();
        System.out.println(log);
    };
}

static void waitForCompletion(ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor) throws InterruptedException {
    while (threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() != 0) {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting Stage-1.
Thread: 2,  Start: 18:27:07.482,  Stop: 18:27:12.487,  ActiveCount: 4,  CorePoolSize: 4
Thread: 3,  Start: 18:27:07.482,  Stop: 18:27:12.487,  ActiveCount: 4,  CorePoolSize: 4
Thread: 1,  Start: 18:27:07.482,  Stop: 18:27:12.487,  ActiveCount: 4,  CorePoolSize: 4
Thread: 4,  Start: 18:27:07.482,  Stop: 18:27:12.487,  ActiveCount: 4,  CorePoolSize: 4
Thread: 5,  Start: 18:27:12.488,  Stop: 18:27:17.491,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 4
Thread: 6,  Start: 18:27:17.492,  Stop: 18:27:22.497,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 4
Thread: 7,  Start: 18:27:22.497,  Stop: 18:27:27.502,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 4
Thread: 8,  Start: 18:27:27.502,  Stop: 18:27:32.506,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 4
Thread: 9,  Start: 18:27:32.506,  Stop: 18:27:37.512,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 4
Thread: 10,  Start: 18:27:37.512,  Stop: 18:27:42.515,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 4
Stage-1 complete.
Starting Stage-2.
Thread: 3,  Start: 18:27:57.504,  Stop: 18:28:02.506,  ActiveCount: 6,  CorePoolSize: 6
Thread: 5,  Start: 18:27:57.504,  Stop: 18:28:02.506,  ActiveCount: 6,  CorePoolSize: 6
Thread: 6,  Start: 18:27:57.504,  Stop: 18:28:02.506,  ActiveCount: 5,  CorePoolSize: 6
Thread: 4,  Start: 18:27:57.504,  Stop: 18:28:02.506,  ActiveCount: 3,  CorePoolSize: 6
Thread: 2,  Start: 18:27:57.504,  Stop: 18:28:02.506,  ActiveCount: 3,  CorePoolSize: 6
Thread: 1,  Start: 18:27:57.504,  Stop: 18:28:02.506,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 6
Thread: 7,  Start: 18:28:02.507,  Stop: 18:28:07.512,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 6
Thread: 8,  Start: 18:28:07.512,  Stop: 18:28:12.517,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 6
Thread: 9,  Start: 18:28:12.517,  Stop: 18:28:17.522,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 6
Thread: 10,  Start: 18:28:17.522,  Stop: 18:28:22.524,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 6
Stage-2 complete.
```

In the above program, you will see the 10 Threads being executed, first with a corePoolSize of 4. After the execution of the first four threads, the execution continues executing sequentially even though the corePoolSize is set higher than 1. I have demonstrated the above findings twice with 2 stages with corePoolSize of 4 and 6, confirming the uniformity of the behaviour.

My expectation is when there is empty slot in the executor, it should utilise that.

Comment: On JDK 20 this program fails with: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1561) at com.example.demo.PoolTest.main(PoolTest.java:20)` because the argument to setCorePoolSize` is more than the `maximumPoolSize`

Comment: If you use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)` you get the expected behaviour. Which JDK are you running with?

Comment: yes @tgdavies . Setting the initial size of ThreadPoolExecutor to 4 does eliminate the issue. I am using OpenJDK by Zulu build 1.8.0_362-b09

Comment: Side note: this use of `AtomicInteger` is entirely obsolete. You could achieve the same result by simply passing `i` as first argument to the `task(…)` call. Besides that, the documentation of `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` does not say anywhere that you can assume the return value to be an instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` to begin with. If you want a configurable thread pool, do not use a factory method even having “fixed” in its name. Instantiate a `ThreadPoolExecutor` explicitly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am answering my question. Thanks to @tgdavies for providing the exception thrown in JDK 20. The solution is to increase the maxPoolSize.

After setting the maxPoolSize to something like

```java
threadPoolExecutor.setMaximumPoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

Things are executing parallely.

Answer (score -2):

You are on a wrong track, completely.

```
String log = "Thread: " + count +
             ",  Start: " + start +
             ",  Stop: " + end +
             ",  ActiveCount: " + threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() +
             ",  CorePoolSize: " + threadPoolExecutor.getCorePoolSize();
System.out.println(log);
```

That snippet above is from inside your method `task()`. It displays something like

```bash
Thread: 5,  Start: 18:27:12.488,  Stop: 18:27:17.491,  ActiveCount: 1,  CorePoolSize: 4
```

But the value of "Thread" is not the thread count or number, but the number of the Task (more precise, of the `Runnable` returned by `task()`). Meaning that your code does not tell you anything about the running threads.

Your statement

> In the above program, you will see the 10 Threads being executed

is wrong. Because the code is in `task()`, it shows just that this method is executed, but nothing about threads.

You forgot that during its lifetime a `Thread` from a pool can execute multiple `Runnable` instances, one after the other. That's why you have a pool. Refer to [the Javadoc for `Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) that describes the intention of the `ExecutorService`.